# Multiple ajax post requests returns invalid code after working for 1st

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser

I successfully logged-in to this site, then I opened chrome dev tools and tried to execute following,

```
$.post("https://www.example.co.uk/request/id",{ entity_id: "637" }, function(data, status){ console.log("entity_id: 637 Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);});
$.post("https://www.example.co.uk/request/id",{ entity_id: "67" }, function(data, status){ console.log("entity_id: 67 Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);});
$.post("https://www.example.co.uk/request/id",{ entity_id: "19920" }, function(data, status){ console.log("entity_id: 19920 Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);});
```

Response I get is,

```
entity_id: 637 Data: {"code":700,"msg":"Example Entity Object"}
Status: success
VM130:3 entity_id: 67 Data: {"code":0,"msg":"Invalid Request."}
Status: success
VM130:2 entity_id: 19920 Data: {"code":0,"msg":"Invalid Request."}
Status: success
```

Initially I thought this website doesn't support parallel post queries, but when I execute these requests one by one regardless of getting response of each requests first, I don't get Invalid request.

I tried Postman as well but there is some authentication problem so I am not using that anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because your php do not listen requests when he is treating an other request. There are two ways in other to resolve your problem:

- Accelerate your php (I can not help you, you do not display your code);
- Slow down your requests like this:

  ```
  var i = 0;
  $.post("https://www.example.co.uk/request/id", { entity_id: "637" }, function (data, status) { console.log("entity_id: 637 Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status); });

  setTimeout(function () {
    $.post("https://www.example.co.uk/request/id", { entity_id: "67" }, function (data, status) { console.log("entity_id: 67 Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status); });
  }, i += 500);

  setTimeout(function () {
    $.post("https://www.example.co.uk/request/id", { entity_id: "19920" }, function (data, status) { console.log("entity_id: 19920 Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status); });
  }, i += 500);
  ```

Also, you can try multiple requests in multiple servers. The servers will, probably, response normally and you can check if the javascript can treat multiple requests but I think yes.

Comment: Thank you, I don't have control over php server, it's a third party website

Comment: 100 didn't helped so I increased timeout to 5000 from 100 and it worked, thanks again